# Html.BeginRouteForm onsucess function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Html.BeginRouteForm in my MVC app. the code looks like

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { controller = "RegisterAPi", httproute = "true" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

I would like at add a js function to call on success. I have jQuery and knockout to use. can anyone help.

Comment: I think you are trying to add ajax functionality to a regular form.
If you would like to add onsuccess, oncomplete etc you will need an ajax beginform - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Could not seem to get the ajax begingform to work the API Rout. And that seems to add lots of overhead to the page. I like the BeginRoutForm. it submits the page to the API without a pare reload. but there does not seem to be a way to get a response from the API.  If I use Ajax in the JavaScript I and post the info and get back info onSuccess...

Comment: You could try ajax from JS. Probably the best choice here! I don't know what you are trying to build but if you are using web api you might want to look into knockoutjs.com for the frontend.